# Почему при добавлении комментария в админке джанго ошибка?

Tags: python, django, админка

При добавлении комментария в админке получаю ошибку:
Ошибка типа в / admin / newsapp / comment / add /
**str** вернул не строку (тип NoneType)
Метод запроса:  ПОЧТА

URL запроса:    http://127.0.0.1:5000/admin/newsapp/comment/add/

версия Django:  3.0.8

Тип исключения: TypeError

Значение исключения:

**str** вернул не строку (тип NoneType)

Местоположение исключения:  C: \ Users \ Миша \ AppData \ Local \ Programs \ Python \ Python37-32 \ lib \ site-packages \ django \ contrib \ admin \ options.py в log_addition, строка 807
Исполняемый файл Python:    C: \ Users \ Миша \ AppData \ Local \ Programs \ Python \ Python37-32 \ python.exe
Версия Python:  3.7.4
Путь Python:
[ 'D: \ \ Python Django \ первый \ \ первые приложения',
'D: \ \ Python Django \ первый',
'C: \ Users \ AppData \ Миша \ Local \ \ Программы Python \ Python37-32 \ python37.zip',
'C: \ Users \ AppData \ Миша \ Local \ \ Программы Python \ Python37-32 \ библиотеки DLL',
'C: \ Users \ AppData \ Миша \ Local \ \ Программы Python \ Python37-32 \ Lib',
'C: \ Users \ AppData \ Миша \ Local \ \ Программы Python \ Python37-32',
'C: \ Users \ AppData \ Миша \ Local \ \ Программы Python \ Python37-32 \ Lib \ сайт-пакеты']

Из-за чего такое может быть?

КОД models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    test = models.ForeignKey(News, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField('Имя комментатора',max_length = 30)
    text = models.TextField('Содержание комментария',max_length = 1000)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def __str__(self):
        verbose_name = 'Комментарий'
        verbase_name_plural = 'Комментарии'
```

Comment: Из-за того что кто-то должен был вернуть стринг, а вернул None. Убедись что все твои классы всегда везвращают стринг при попытке представить их в строке. Если не получится пиши, я скажу где искать)

Comment: Добавил отрывок кода из models.py

Comment: Все я понял свою ошибку!Я вместо класса Meta для Comment написал функцию.

Comment: я что-то понять не могу, вы что, текст ошибки переводчиком переводили?

Comment: Да,ну он автоматом кажись сам перевел)